# Merging two Applications into one

Tags: objective-c, merge

What I have are two separate applications:

1) A regular application
2) An application that displays different applications and "launches" them

The second application is basically a display for all the applications there are so far. I will have it so that if you click on one of the applications in it, you will launch that application.

What I **DON'T** want is to exit the application and go into the other one. I want the application to launch within.

What I assume I'm supposed to do is merge the two codes together. But they both have app delegates.

I'm wondering that the best method is for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think of it as two apps. As far as the framework is concerned, you've got ONE app here. It happens to have two sections, but it's one app.

Comment: So I just copy and pasted all my files into one of the applications, including the app delegates and info plist and such. I'm getting a lot of errors, any suggestions?

Comment: Well it'll probably take more than just blindly moving files. And you definitely DON'T want to move the app delegates and info plists over.